# How can Japan have much lower inflation compared to US when Yen is much weaker compared to USD than 1 year ago?

Tags: inflation, exchange-rates

I understand that Japanese people might not buy same stuff that US people buy, that inflation might be calculated differently, that people in Japan can buy services/products made inside Japan... and other similar arguments, but the difference seems too big.

1y ago exchange rate was 110, now it is 143. That is gigantic difference, over 20% drop.
Official US inflation is around 8%, Japan inflation is around 3%.

Comment: What is the theory behind your assumption that inflation should be a result of a depreciating currency?

Comment: US and Japan import X from some third country. X cost 10 USD / 1100Yen 1y ago. If US consumers now need 10.80USD to pay for it Japanese consumers need 1133 Yen to buy it(assuming average inflation rates apply to X). Issue is that today 1133 Yen is much less than 10.80$

Comment: The exchange rate was 115 on March 6, 2022. That's only 6 months ago. The exchange rate can change rapidly as money flows between dollars and Yen. Inflation won't change as quickly. Japan has a large economy with lots of inertia. So even if the inflation rate does follow the exchange rate, there will be a significant delay. And as you pointed out in your question, there are many other factors that will cloud the correlation between the exchange rate and the inflation rate. The biggest factor is that the exchange rate is precisely known, but the inflation rate is just a fuzzy guesstimate.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/67940/54838) useful.